# problem in custom listview

Tags: android

```
public class SampleInbox extends ListActivity {
    private EfficientAdapter adap;
    String strUrl;
    InboxBean iBean;
    InboxBean inboxBean;
    XmlParser parser;
    ArrayList<Object>  result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_content);
        adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adap);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Context context;
        String strUrl;
        InboxBean iBean;
        InboxBean inboxBean;
        XmlParser parser;
        ArrayList<Object>  result;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;

            strUrl = "http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_test/index.php?option=com_community&view=frontpage&task=inbox_xml&id="+ConstantData.user_id+"&sessionid="+ConstantData.session_id+"&tmpl=component";
            parser = new XmlParser(strUrl, new InboxBean());
            result = parser.ParseUrl("data", "message");
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_content, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine);
                holder.iconLine = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconLine);
                holder.txtBodyList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBodyList);
                holder.txtPostDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPostDate);

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    private int pos = position;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    }
                });


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.iconLine.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
            // holder.textLine.setText("flag " + String.valueOf(position));

            for(int i=0; i<result.size(); ++i)
            {

                iBean = (InboxBean)result.get(i);
                holder.textLine.setText(iBean.subject);
                holder.txtBodyList.setText(iBean.body);
                Log.d("Position", ""+iBean);
                Log.d("Position", ""+iBean.subject);
                holder.txtPostDate.setText(iBean.postdate);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView textLine;
            ImageView iconLine;
            //  Button buttonLine;
            TextView txtBodyList;
            TextView txtPostDate;
        }
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @     Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("Counter", ""+result.size());
            return result.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In above code, i am getting records from webservice. The problem is that there are total 12 records and i am getting 12 records but in each row the last record is print please give me solution

Comment: You are receiving 12 records from the Webservice. The last record is print. I couldn't get you here... Are you getting "print" in all columns of the last row?

Comment: i am getting 12 rows with same data(last record)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have for loop in your adapter class...which was not needed at all....if u want to assign value to textboxes then just do it for only one time..remove for loop...